# javascript img onclick reference error to function

Tags: javascript

I keep on getting `ReferenceError: toggleExpand is not defined` in console on firefox when I click the img

I am trying to get the image to enlarging, floating in center screen on click, no jquery, pure javascript, html, css.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleExpand(id){
      var doc = document.getElementById(id);
      doc.style.z-index = "1";
      doc.style.width = "512px";
      doc.style.align = "center";
    }
  </script>
  <img id="img1" onclick="toggleExpand('img1');" src="I:\Images\image.jpg" alt="image" style="width:128px; height:auto; cursor:pointer; z-index:0"/>
</body>
```

Comment: a jsFiddle will help us!

Comment: Try to shift the script tag to Head and check once.

Comment: I cant place scripts in head do to limitations in moodle.

Comment: change `doc.style.z-index` to `doc.style['z-index']` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `doc.style.z-index` to `doc.style['z-index']` and check

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggleExpand(id) {
        var doc = document.getElementById(id);
        doc.style['z-index'] = "1";
        doc.style.width = "512px";
        doc.style.align = "center";
      }
    </script>
    <img id="img1" onclick="toggleExpand('img1');" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Alexanderplatz_Stadtmodell_1.jpg/1920px-Alexanderplatz_Stadtmodell_1.jpg" alt="image" style="width:128px; height:auto; cursor:pointer; z-index:0"
    />
  </body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code used this  can used this

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
           function toggle(){
               var doc = document.getElementById("divSection");

                    doc.style.z-index = "1";
                    doc.style.width = "512px";
                   doc.style.align = "center";
          }
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>
        <p class="button" onclick="toggle()">Show/hide</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, a property cannot contain a `-`
so change it to CamelCase `zIndex` or wrap in brackets `["z-index"]`

---

also, *strange no-one mentioned*, **no need to pass the ID!** You already have the `this` reference to the clicked referring HTMLIMGElement,
so yes, use simply `onclick="toggleExpand(this);"` without the ID

Also I see you named your function `TOGGLE...` so let's **toggle**!

```css
img[onclick]{vertical-align:top; cursor:pointer; }
```

```html
<script>
  function toggleExpand(el){
    var io = el.tog ^= 1;                 // Store the toggle state
    el.style.zIndex = io ? 1 : 0;
    el.style.width = (io ? 256 : 128) +"px";
  }
</script>

<img onclick="toggleExpand(this);" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6edc0ac8cd9f3e790389f3284eaaf9e9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image" style="width:128px; height:auto;  z-index:0"/>
<img onclick="toggleExpand(this);" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIkv.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="image" style="width:128px; height:auto;  z-index:0"/>
```

***[jsBin playground](http://jsbin.com/yiruzi/1/edit?html,css,console,output)***

Answer (score 0):

Why you are passing your id as a function argument! why not use something like this-

```
<body>
<img id="img1" onclick="toggleExpand();" src="I:\Images\image.jpg" alt="image" style="width:128px; height:auto; cursor:pointer; z-index:0"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleExpand(){
  var doc = document.getElementById('img1');
  doc.style.z-index = "1";
  doc.style.width = "512px";
  doc.style.align = "center";
}
</script>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do in this way.

```
var doc = document.getElementById(id)    
doc.addEventListener('click',toggleExpand);
```